# Is explicit update required in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

In most of the hibernate applications i see the  explicit update statement to update any hibernate entity in db

```
    Session session1 = factory.openSession();
    Transaction  tx1 = session1.beginTransaction();
    College college= (College)session1.get(College.class, 1);
    college.setCollegeName("College_update");
    session1.saveOrUpdate(college); // at line 1
    tx1.commit();
    session1.close();
```

But even i miss statement 1 , entity is updated in DB. My question is it a good practice to mention explicit update statement
when it is not required even ?

Comment: No, it's not good practice. Most of the code you've seen is from people not understanding fundamental features of Hibernate.

Comment: saveOrUpdate does not mean that the data is saved to the DB ,Need to  commit the transaction  to confirm saving the data to the DB. saveOrUpdate  only issues the UPDATE SQL without any COMMIT to the DB.You can rollback the data if any errors are found later.

Comment: @Shayan saveOrUpdate() doesn't even issue a SQL update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the saveOrUpdate statement is not required. The College entity is attached to your Hibernate session because is was instantiated by Hibernate. Any mutations to the College entity will be UPDATEd to the database when that session is flushed.

Use saveOrUpdate when you need to attach an existing (detached) entity to a hibernate session. Any subsequent mutations to that entity made in the scope of that session will be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Update is required to take data from one session or transaction and save it into the database in another transaction.

```
 A a = session1.load(......);
 // Commit transaction

//Start New session ......

 //Start transaction
 session2.update (a);
```

If you read an entity change its properties within the same session then the results will get saved when you flush the session.